# Was the wide use of mercury in experiments in the 19th century related to alchemy?

Tags: physics, chemistry, electricity, alchemy

We know that Newton's hair samples showed high level of mercury and of course he used mercury like crazy in his alchemy experiments (as did many/all alchemists not just in the west but also China) and in fact Newton had some concern about this or at least thought it affected his hair color (he made some comment about this specifically). The dangers of mercury were not unknown then and by the 19th century they must have been fairly well established although mercury continued to be prescribed as a medicine (and dental filling material as an amalgam) during the US civil war and even into the 20th century for syphilis although by then it was used more topically. Even now I think Mercurochrome is still used as a topical disinfectant in some countries.

We know also that Faraday used mercury so much that he believed, quite reasonably, that it was affecting his cognition/memory. Now, mercury used medicinally is quite different than using it in electrical experiments as Faraday used it -- I believe the first electrical motor of Faraday involved a pool of the element.

Mercury is a good conductor and it also is probably at that time the only conductor that was liquid at room temperature. Was mercury's wide use in experiments due to its physical properties or did it retain some of the glamour from the days of alchemy -- did scientists like Faraday believe it had some special properties beyond the measurable physical properties just as Newton did?

Comment: Newton was deeply involved in [alchemical studies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isaac_Newton%27s_occult_studies). See BJT Dobbs, [The Foundations of Newton's Alchemy](https://books.google.it/books?id=wwc4AAAAIAAJ&printsec=frontcover) as well as William R. Newman, [Newton the Alchemist](https://books.google.it/books?id=NXGYDwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover).

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA: I thought I implied that well-known fact about Newton in the question. I will be explicit.

Comment: Your question is riddled with inaccuracies and incorrect claims.   Hg amalgam for dental work is 100% nontoxic, for example.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft: Where did I say dental amalgams are toxic and what claims are inaccurate or incorrect in your opinion? Re amalgams, why would a physicist have a strong or reliable opinion about toxicity of anything?

Comment: (1) "dangers...well established although.... amalgam"  clearly implies amalgam is dangerous.   (2) If you think physicists don't take toxicities into account you must be thinking of some microsubset of physicists such as String Theorists

Comment: I was enumerating uses of mercury. "Riddled" implies many -- besides your problem with my mentioning amalgams, what is another inaccuracy or incorrect claim? The question is about why Faraday (and others) used mercury -- it is certainly due to dangers of mercury exposure not used nearly as widely today. For example, mercury cathodes were once used (perhaps as late as 1990) to manufacture bleach but this is no longer the case. Do not stupidly argue that mercury is not dangerous.

Comment: Only to the extent that chemistry emerged out of alchemic practices in 17-18th century, and some devices and technical procedures that used mercury were inherited from it. But interest in alchemy proper was already outdated at the time of Newton's death in 1727, which is why his alchemic notebooks weren't published by the estate. Faraday was familiar with mercury from his chemical research and imported it into his electromagnetic research as it was a conveniently liquid metal. There is no interest in alchemy recorded in his detailed notebooks.

Comment: @Conifold: That is probably it -- devices that used mercury had origins in mercury. I did not really think that Faraday believed in transmutation using Hg but he could have nonetheless had some sort of "respect" for the element that was inherited from alchemists.

Comment: O'Brien quotes from Faraday's *Chemical Manipulation* in [Faraday's Health Problems](http://acshist.scs.illinois.edu/bulletin_open_access/num11/num11%20p47-50.pdf). For his use in electromagnetic experiments see [Gross](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2850252/).